# Massive misuse of 'webview' tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, android, osx

The description of [webview](/questions/tagged/webview) says

> A NSView subclass that displays web pages under MacOS. For Android, please look at the android-webview tag. For iOS, look under uiwebview.

However, I noticed that most people use the webview tag for Android and (to a lesser degree) for iOS and iPhone.

- [android](/questions/tagged/android)[webview](/questions/tagged/webview) [3632 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webview+android)
- [ios](/questions/tagged/ios)[webview](/questions/tagged/webview) [220 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webview+ios)
- [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone)[webview](/questions/tagged/webview) [229 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webview+iphone)
- [cocoa](/questions/tagged/cocoa)[webview](/questions/tagged/webview) [303 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webview+cocoa)
- [osx](/questions/tagged/osx)[webview](/questions/tagged/webview) [153 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webview+osx)
- [webview](/questions/tagged/webview) and not [android](/questions/tagged/android),[cocoa](/questions/tagged/cocoa),[osx](/questions/tagged/osx),[ios](/questions/tagged/ios) or [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone) [493 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webview+-ios+-android+-osx+-cocoa+-iphone)

How do we clean up this mess? The way I see it we have 3 options:

1. We keep the current webview tag description and retag all Android questions to [android-webview](/questions/tagged/android-webview) and all iOS and iPhone questions to [uiwebview](/questions/tagged/uiwebview)
2. We change the description of webview tag and start using it only for Android. We retag all cocoa and osx questions to  a newly created [osx-webview](/questions/tagged/osx-webview)
3. We adjust the webview tag description and allow both Android, Cocoa and OS X questions.
4. We deprecate the webview tag and only use specific tags. <sup>(Suggested by [Mr. Disappointment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175272/massive-misuse-of-webview-tag#comment-525379))</sup>

Personally, I'm in favour of option 4 but I'm curious what you think.

**UPDATE June 5th 2013:** It seems that someone went for option 3 and updated the webview tag to a more general description.

Comment: Of course they do, when they're working with Android, why would they think `webview` was for anything else? The solution would be to have unique tags, if the tag is at all necessary, i.e. deprecate [tag:webview] and mark _all_ explicitly: [tag:android-webview], [tag:ios-webview], and the rest.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment I think Android users are much sloppier than iOS users because there are 1859 questions properly tagged android-webview and 5322 questions properly tagged with uiwebview. But I do like your idea to make the webview tag deprecated

Comment: Webkit and webview are used elsewhere too, such as in [Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=webview+qt). What ever is done, the solution should include how to properly tag these, too. I think options `1` and `2` don't handle this very well.

Comment: Regarding your Update, see http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1920437

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i'd think option 3 would make the most sense, since "webview" could then be generically used for "i have a question about embedding a webview (regardless of platform), while the platform tags would allow the user to differentiate. (ie "webview + android", "webview + Qt", or whatever.

as a symmetrical example, if there was a tag "button", you'd expect it to apply to questions about working with buttons in your UI in general, and not be specific to, say, the WPF Button class.

just my .2

Comment: Good point about `button`. Maybe `webview` could be generic, but keep all the framework-specific `foo-webview` tags also. There is a [tag:button], and it's being used just as you described. There's also e.g. [tag:uibutton]. So why not define `webview` as "any kind of webview" and just leave the other variants alone...

Comment: .2? Did you mean $.02?

Answer (score 3):

Option 4 seems like a reasonable candidate.  To keep track of people's preferences, upvote this answer if you prefer Option 4.  In particular:

The set of tags would be [android-webview](/questions/tagged/android-webview), [osx-webview](/questions/tagged/osx-webview), and [uiwebview](/questions/tagged/uiwebview) (optionally, one could add [ios-webview](/questions/tagged/ios-webview) and make it a synonym for [uiwebview](/questions/tagged/uiwebview), if you care about consistency in naming).  Then, deprecate the [webview](/questions/tagged/webview) tag.